# plink not echoing stderr

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I am using plink to run commands on a windows server running openssh. It appears that plink doesn't echo output that is on stderr. For example, where bork.exe prints "stdout" to stdout and "stderr" to stderr:

```
plink -no-antispoof -ssh user@example -pw topsecret c:\somewhere\bork.exe
```

The output on the console is:

```
stdout
```

I've tried various methods, none of which work. For example, this does't work:

```
plink -no-antispoof -ssh user@example -pw topsecret c:\somewhere\bork.exe 2^>^&1
```

Oddly, creating c:\somewhere\blah.cmd, containing

```
c:\somewhere\bork
```

and then

```
plink -no-antispoof -ssh user@example -pw topsecret cmd /c c:\somewhere\blah.cmd
```

prints:

```
c:\somewhere\bork
```

Do you know how I can get stderr to be echoed to the console?

Comment: If I do `plink -no-antispoof user@example.com "echo stdout & echo stderr >&2"` – I get both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Hmm. I get no output when I do that. I am using plink 0.73. What version are you using? Or, maybe it has to do with me running openssh on windows.

Comment: Also Plink 0.73. And also against OpenSSH on Windows (the `&` has a different meaning with common Linux shells) – What OpenSSH are you using? How did you install it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The server is running openssh 8.1 on windows. So both client and server are windows, no linux. I installed it via these instructions https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Comment: I have it installed the same way, but that gives me OpenSSH 7.7.

Comment: Well, that is odd, unless there is a difference between when we installed it.

Comment: I even uninstalled and reinstalled it.

Comment: Oops. It was these instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#installing-openssh-with-powershell